# I think I made a bit of a mess, how to solve it

Tags: discussion, duplicates

In a short time I asked three questions about more or less about the same subject:

[which surfaces have (for a large area) a constant negative curvature?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930847/which-surfaces-have-for-a-large-area-a-constant-negative-curvature)

["Hyperboloid like surface" as hyperbolic plane / pseudosphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927507/hyperboloid-like-surface-as-hyperbolic-plane-pseudosphere)

and 
(on math overflow)

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180912/besides-the-tracioid-are-there-other-surfaces-of-revolution-that-have-a-constant

(each time getting different good answers, the subject is just rather confusing)

After some more studying I now know more about the subject (the subject is just larger and more confusing than I previously realised)

Now I think it is interesting for others who would like to know more about this confusing subject. (even some respected textbooks have I think  misinterpretations)

Can I make a new question and answer it myself  (with linking to the questions above )  or are there better ways  to cleanup the mess I made?

Or would this just increase the confusing?

Comment: I think a better way would be to leave only one of the questions and ask moderators to collect all the answers under it.

Comment: To post a new question and answer it yourself would just increase the confusion in this case. Sometimes, a question has to be asked because you honestly don't know the answer. What if the subject turns out to be even larger and more confusing than you think it is right now?